# Order of execution of C operators

Tags: c, operators

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i;
    i = 10;
    i*= 10+2;
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

why is the output of the following code 120 and not 102?

Comment: `i *= 10+2` is `i = i * (10+2)`

Comment: And this question is the very reason that `i*= 10+2;` is **bad code**:  it's not immediately and explicitly clear what it does.  (And if you do think that code is OK and demonstrating your knowledge of the subtleties of C operator precedence is something that makes your code better, what is so *wrong* with rest of your code that you think it needs help from that minutiae to stand out?)

Comment: The two options you have here is that i ends up being 120 or 100. 102 does not make sense. It's either `i *= (10 +2)` or `(i *= 10) +2`.

Comment: Your beginner-level C book will have the answer, in the section called operator precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the order of precedence makes '+' higher than *=, so the 10+2 will occur befor the i *=.

C reference for ordering at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 0):

In this Line 
i*= 10+2;
In this case the 12 multiply by i It Means
i=10*12;
So it Will Give 120 In answer

To solve this issue
Try This.

```
i*= 10;
i+=2;
```

Comment: Could you explain the precedence of operators to add to this answer, saying why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

your code work like .

```
i= i*(10+2)
```

so it give the answer like 120.

if you wanna answer like 102 the do .

```
i=i*10+2
```

Answer (score -1):

This

```
i*= 10 + 2;
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
i= i * (10 + 2);
```

the rest is precedence left to right, add and subst after mult./division

Comment: I'm not really sure why this was downvoted, as this seems like the clearest way to understand what's going on. Perhaps two people were upset that you glossed over the fact that the compound assignment operators have precedence of their own, and are not actually decomposed in the manner you describe?

Comment: I haven't voted, but this doesn't answer the question as asked.   The explanation is that `*=` has lower precedence than `+`, not that `*=` is syntactic sugar.

Comment: Bit harsh to down vote because of this subtle detail, but this is _not_ just syntactic sugar. See 6.5.16 "A compound assignment of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to the simple assignment
expression E1 = E1 op (E2), except that the lvalue E1 is evaluated only once". Does it matter? Yes, if evaluating the operand causes a side effect. Suppose for example that `i` is declared as volatile. `i*= a + b;` is then _not_ the same thing as `i = i * (a + b);`.

Comment: A real-world example: "In the register STATUS, the flag RX is cleared by a read followed by a write."  Code such as `STATUS |= TX;` will then work as expected, while the code `STATUS = STATUS | TX;` will destroy the flag RX. Cases like these are for example common when working with serial bus hardware such as UART, SPI, I2C or CAN.